# How to add tags on specific Resourcegroups?

Tags: azure, powershell, tags

I need to add tags on only the ResourceGroups (which I don't know the name of) where a Keyvault is in. It is possible that there are more than one Keyvaults in several Resourcegroups.
This is how I tried:

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionID
#Add Currentdate on resourcegroup of Keyvault

$CurrentDate = ((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))

$Tags = @{'Date' = $Currentdate}


$Resources = (Get-AzKeyVault).ResourceGroupName


Foreach ($Resource in $Resources){

$ResourcegroupName = (Get-AzKeyVault).ResourceGroupName
$ResourcegroupId = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourcegroupName).ResourceId
    New-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourcegroupId -Tag $Tags
    }
```

The commands work separately but in this context it gives multiple errors (below error 3 times). Getting the ResourceId gives by what I can see the main error:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:11 char:47
+ ... sourcegroupId = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourcegroupName).Resour ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzResourceGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceGroupCmdlet

New-AzTag : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:12 char:27
+     New-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourcegroupId -Tag $Tags
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-AzTag], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Tags.Tag.NewAzureTagCommand
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Not sure why are you doing this - `$ResourcegroupName = (Get-AzKeyVault).ResourceGroupName`? This will give you an array of resource group names. Right?

Comment: Yes this is to get the array of the several ResourceGroups, because I need to add on every ResourceGroup the same tag.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you need to add tags on only the ResourceGroups where a Keyvault is in.

I modified a bit your code:

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionID
#Add Currentdate on resourcegroup of Keyvault

$CurrentDate = ((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))

$Tags = @{'Date' = $Currentdate}

$Resources = (Get-AzKeyVault).ResourceGroupName

Foreach ($Resource in $Resources){
    $ResourcegroupId = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $Resource).ResourceId
    New-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourcegroupId -Tag $Tags
}
```